# How to prevent a child destroying in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am preparing a puzzle game. I can drag and drop from down generated sticks to up places. Let's say that there are two sticks on the first node and we have 2 more sticks in bottom. We can drag it to right place and make them one parent again. I can make them one parent but second stick from buttom is destroying when i drop on the first node. 
In this picture it is aqua color:

before drop

[image: before drop photo]

after drop

[image: after drop photo]

---

How to resolve this issue?

```
if(nodes[smallestId].transform.childCount > 0)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < rayhit.transform.childCount; i++)
  {
    nodes[smallestId].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Node>().sticks.Add(rayhit.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Stick>());
    rayhit.transform.GetChild(i).transform.SetParent(nodes[smallestId].transform.GetChild(0));
  }
  Destroy(rayhit.transform.gameObject);
}
else
{ 
  rayhit.transform.SetParent(nodes[smallestId].transform);
  Debug.Log("Stick : " + nodes[smallestId].transform);
}
```

Comment: This is too complicated for anyone to answer, I reckon...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you iterate over `rayhit.transform.childCount`.

When you remove a child due to `rayhit.transform.GetChild(i).transform.SetParent` the  `rayhit.transform.childCount` is already reduced by one.

Therefore in the next iteration `i` might already be greater then `rayhit.transform.childCount` so e.g. the second object is not moved to the new parent!

Instead You could use

```
// do this only once
var targetParent = nodes[smallestId].transform;

if(targetParent > 0)
{
    targetParent = targetParent.GetChild(0);
    // do also this only once
    var node = targetParent.GetComponent<Node>();

    var toMove = new List<Transform>();
    foreach (Transform child in rayhit.transform)
    {
        node.sticks.Add(child.GetComponent<Stick>());
        toMove.Add(child);
    }
    foreach(var child in toMove)
    {
        child.SetParent(targetParent);
    }

    Destroy(rayhit.transform.gameObject);
}
else
{ 
    rayhit.transform.SetParent(targetParent);
    Debug.Log("Stick : " + targetParent);
}
```

Which first stores them all in a list so you don't depend on whether they already where moved to a new parent or not.

---

As alternative I think you could even rather use [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html) here which would completely save you from the trouble and you wouldn't need to use two loops at all:

```
var targetParent = nodes[smallestId].transform;

if(targetParent > 0)
{
    targetParent = targetParent.GetChild(0);
    // do also this only once
    var node = targetParent.GetComponent<Node>();

    // These references now don't depend on their parent object
    // so you can safely iterate on them without any issues
    foreach (var stick in rayhit.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Stick>(true))
    {
        node.sticks.Add(stick);
        stick.transform.SetParent(targetParent);
    }

    Destroy(rayhit.transform.gameObject);
}
else
{ 
    rayhit.transform.SetParent(targetParent);
    Debug.Log("Stick : " + targetParent);
}
```

Comment: with this code I got
Transform child out of bounds (error)
and error line is

                        nodes[smallestId].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Node>().sticks.Add(child.GetComponent<Stick>());

Comment: While this is a classic problem (iterating while mutating a collection), and can be tackled using your suggestion, the `Object.Destroy()` method doesn't do anything until the end of the current update loop, so I don't think that's it in this case.

Comment: @trojanfoe it is not the `Destroy` that makes the problem but as said rather the `SetParent` which transfers the child objects to a different parent object so that the `childCount` changes while iterating on it

Comment: @israfiluzuk the `nodes[smallestId].transform.GetChild(0)` was taken from your example, ofcourse you still have to wrap the entire code block it in your `if-else` check - see update

Answer (score -1):

guys here is solution :)

```
rayhit.transform.position = nodes[smallestId].transform.position;
                    if (rayhit.transform.parent != nodes[smallestId].transform)
                    { 
                        if (nodes[smallestId].transform.childCount > 0 && nodes[smallestId].transform != rayhit.transform.parent)
                        {
                            if (currNode != null)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < currNode.sticks.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    nodes[smallestId].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Node>().sticks.Add(currNode.sticks[i]);
                                    currNode.sticks[i].transform.SetParent(nodes[smallestId].transform.GetChild(0));
                                }
                                Destroy(rayhit.transform.gameObject);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (currNode != null)
                            {
                                currNode.isMoved = true;
                            }
                            rayhit.transform.SetParent(nodes[smallestId].transform);
                        }
                    }
```

Thank you for your help.